# Converter PDF para Word sem perder os estilos

Tags: java, pdf, microsoft-word

Queria um codigo para converter um documento pdf em word sem perder os estilos.

Tenho essa classe que converte para word mais ele não mantem os estilos do documento.

```
public class teste {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     System.out.println("Document converted started");
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
    String pdf = "C:\\Users\\eder\\Downloads\\teste1111.pdf";
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        TextExtractionStrategy strategy = parser.processContent(i,
                new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
        String text = strategy.getResultantText();
        XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = p.createRun();
        run.setText(text);
        run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
    }
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\eder\\Downloads\\testandoWord.docx");
    doc.write(out);
    out.close();
    reader.close();
    System.out.println("Document converted successfully");
}
```

Estou usando a iText e POI. Ja dei uma olhada na documentação mas nao achei nada no estilo que eu preciso. Exemplo de pdf: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Você está usando o iText? Se sim, a estratégia `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` não mantém estilos. Você teria que estudar a documentação e procurar se existe uma estratégia que faça o parse mantendo o estilo.

Comment: Sim estou usando a iText 5.4.4 e Poi. Vou dar mais uma olhada na documentação.